# How to iterate over properties of an ES6/2015 class instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

given these two classes

```
class Foo{
  f1;

  get f2(){
    return "a";
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  b1;

  get b2(){
    return "a";
  }
}

let bar = new Bar();
```

What code will get me this list of properties from the `bar` instance? `['f1', 'f2', 'b1', 'b2']`

[Here is a Babel sample](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Foo%7B%0A%20%20f1%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20get%20f2()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20b1%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20get%20b2()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0A%0A%0Aconsole.log(Object.keys(bar))%0A)

---

**Update**

This should be part of @Marc C's answer:

Using a decorator I can easily turn a non enumerable property into an enumerable property:

```
class Bar extends Foo {

  @enumerable()  
  get b2(){
    return "a";
  }

}
```

Here is the decorator source:

```
function enumerable() {
  return function(target, key, descriptor) {
    if (descriptor) {
      descriptor.enumerable = true;
    }
  };
}
```

[Here is a Babel sample](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20enumerable()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20function(target%2C%20key%2C%20descriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(descriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%7B%0A%20%20f1%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%40enumerable()%20%20%0A%20%20get%20f2()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20b1%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%0A%20%20%40enumerable()%20%20%0A%20%20get%20b2()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20get%20b3()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0A%0Alet%20props%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Afor(let%20i%20in%20bar)%7B%0A%20%20props.push(i)%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(props)%3B%0A%0A%20%0A%0A%0A)

Comment: This honestly seems like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054910/get-functions-of-a-class. There is no reason to make the properties enumerable.

Comment: [tag:babel]: *"Python internationalization library with an emphasis on web-based applications. For questions about the JavaScript library, please use [babeljs]."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not [valid syntax for declaring properties](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html) in a class. Instead, declare them in the constructor.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.f1 = undefined;
  }
}
```

Then you can get them using `Object.keys`.

Using experimental features in Babel will allow you to declare properties using that syntax but their values must be declared.

```
class Foo {
  f1 = 0;
  ...
}
```

As for accessing the getters, getters are non-enumerable by default and can't be accessed using `Object.keys` or any similar mechanism. However, you can create enumerable getters using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```
Object.defineProperty(bar, 'f2', {
  get() { 
    return "a"; 
  }
});
```

If you're using experimental ES7 features, you can apply a [decorator](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators) to the class method and get the same behavior. See this [Babel sample](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20enumerable()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20function(target%2C%20key%2C%20descriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(descriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%7B%0A%20%20f1%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%40enumerable()%20%20%0A%20%20get%20f2()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20b1%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%0A%20%20%40enumerable()%20%20%0A%20%20get%20b2()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20get%20b3()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22a%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0A%0Alet%20props%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Afor(let%20i%20in%20bar)%7B%0A%20%20props.push(i)%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(props)%3B%0A%0A%20%0A%0A%0A).

```
class Foo {
  @enumerable()
  get b2() {
    return "a";
  }
}

function enumerable() {
  return function(target, key, descriptor) {
    if (descriptor) {
      descriptor.enumerable = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1 - I do use this experimental feature that babel supports (for `f1` and `b1`). 2 - `Object.keys()` does not get me `b2` and `f2`.

Comment: @Sylvain Babel may accept it but if you look at the compiled code, `f1` and `b1` are not declared. Babel will declare them if you assign them values such as `f1 = 0`. As for `f2` and `b2`, [getters are not enumerable by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517538/setting-an-es6-class-getter-to-enumerable).

Comment: good point. 1 - I can fix this (and leave it outside a constructor) if I set them to undefined up there. 2 - Is there a function that will get me the list of these getters or are they truly hidden?

Comment: @Sylvain They're truly hidden when written in that format. Using `Object.defineProperty`, you can make an enumerable getter and that will be visible.

Comment: Check my update above, if you think its a good idea, add it to your answer and I'll accept it (I did not dare update your edit your answer)

Comment: @Sylvain Interesting, I didn't know about ES7 decorators. Updated my answer to include them. Thanks for that.

Comment: One more thing, `Object.keys(bar)` does not work. I had to use `for (let p in bar)` to get all 4 properties. This should be added to your answer too.

Comment: You can easily get all the properties using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, even if they are non-enumerable. Making them enumerable is totally unrelated to being able to list them as long as you don't use `for...in`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054910/get-functions-of-a-class

Comment: I have to get `f1` and `f2` as well which are inherited from `Foo`; `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will not return them.

Comment: As the answer in the question I linked to says, you need to traverse the prototype chain because `getOwnPropertyNames` only returns `own` properties. `for...in` traverses the prototype chain, you need to do that too. In this specific case, the properties are on the direct prototype `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(a))`

Comment: This is of course an old reply, but since it's the chosen answer I thought I'd add that there is a proposal (that's likely to pass) that adds class field declarations https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields and there's a Babel plugin to handle this syntax https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this was answered before. You can apply [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to the instance and its prototypes:

```
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  let names = [];
  do {
    names.push.apply(names, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  } while(obj !== Object.prototype);
  return names.filter(name => name !== 'constructor');
}
```

Comment: This was the only answer that put me on the right track:  
var that = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(that);

just ... wow what a language js is :-O