# How to fetch list or array of all getter setter properies inside generic method in ES6 javascript class?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, es6-class

I created ES6 class which has several properties. Like this :

```
class CustomLocalStorage {
//#region userName
get userName() {
    this._userName = localStorage.getItem("25ciWC16Hh");
    this._userName = this._userName ? decryptText(this._userName) : "";
    return this._userName;
}

set userName(newValue) {
    if(newValue) {
        this._userName = encryptText(newValue + "");
        localStorage.setItem("25ciWC16Hh", this._userName);
    }

}
remove_userName() {
    this._userName = null;
    localStorage.removeItem("25ciWC16Hh");
}
//#endregion userName

//#region webapi
get webapi() {
    this._webapi = localStorage.getItem("ALOrVJuVKt");
    this._webapi = this._webapi;
    return this._webapi;
}

set webapi(newValue) {
    this._webapi = newValue;
    localStorage.setItem("ALOrVJuVKt", this._webapi)
}
remove_webapi() {
    this._webapi = null;
    localStorage.removeItem("ALOrVJuVKt");
}
//#endregion webapi
```

As seen in above code, each property is bonded to the localStorage object. Now, I want one generic method which fetches all getter/setter properties and removes it from localStorage.

So, for that I wrote following method inside the class:

```
removeAll() {
    for (var key in this) {
        if(key != "_settings" && key != "") {
            this[key] = null;
            localStorage.remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not fetching any getter/setter properties. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Aren't your localStorage keys hashed anyway, so that the name of the instance property doesn't help?

Comment: I don't see why you are using those underscore-prefixed properties - they're not even caching anything. Wouldn't local variables be more effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [getters/setters are not enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34517538/1048572) (like basically anything defined in a `class`). You can still [iterate them through `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30881632/1048572) though. In your case:

```
removeAll() {
    for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(CustomLocalStorage.prototype))
        if (name.startsWith("remove_")) // not "removeAll"!
            this[name]();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your idea about the code. Thanks for your help