# Is there a mechanism for converting a class instance to an object which contains keys of the public properties of the interface?

Tags: typescript

i.e. if I have an object Person which looks like

```
class PersonClass implements Person {
  private _name : string;
  private _age : number;
  get name() : string {return this._name}
  get age() : number (return this._age)
  constructor(name : string, age : number) {
     this._name = name;
     this._age = age;
  }
 }
```

And I have interface with the public properties:

```
interface Person {
    name : string;
    age : string;
}
```

And what I need to do is get an object representation of the person which reflects the Person interface, and so looks like

```
{ name: John, age: 23}
```

Is there a way to do that?  I tried casting ( `person as Person` } and JSON.stringify and object assign and I seem to end up with object that contains the private data `_name` and `_age` but not the interface members `name` and `age'

Comment: So you're looking for a new object which *only* contains the properties of the `Person` interface?

Comment: This is strongly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517538/setting-an-es6-class-getter-to-enumerable. Judging by the answers in there, this is actually pretty tricky to make work. Have you thought about just a `toPlainObject` method instead? https://tsplay.dev/wgLQ4N

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what I want to do isn't straightforward, so I ended up using an approach which saves all the state variables in a private object that implements the interface, and when then when I want to get access to the data, I call a function which returns either a clone or the original dataobject.

something like:

```
interface Person {
    name : string;
    age : string;
}

class PersonClass implements Person {
   data : <Person>{} = {}
   constructor(name : string, age : number) {
       this.data.name = name;
       this.data.age = age;
   }
   get name() : string {return data.name}
   get age() : number {return data.age}
   get dataObject : return this.data;
}
```

Not perfect of course, because private can data can be manipulated from outside the class via the .dataObject, but if dataObject returns a deep copy of the data, then encapsulation can be maintained.  A little extra work, but it makes retrieving data reading from a class and writing to the backend a little easier.